# why *ngIf not working with ng-container in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to close bootstrap alert box on click close button with help of *ngIf.

In onClick (close) am calling isError=false. I am able to log isError value as false but ng-container is not disappering?
Here is my code

```
<div class="error-list">
  <ng-container *ngIf="isError">
    <ngb-alert type="danger" (click)="closeError()">{{errorMessage}}</ngb-alert>
  </ng-container>
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <span type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span
        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></span>
    <strong>Warning!</strong> {{errorMessage}}.
  </div>

</div>

.error-list {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

::ng-deep .alert {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

.ts file

```
 closeError(): void {

this.isError = false;
console.log("Message: ", this.isError);
}
```

Comment: @AndrewAllen, Can you explain some more How to mark for check ?

Comment: Try using a `<div>` instead of `<ng-container>`?

Comment: @ShakeerHussain I have tried your scenario and it's working fine without any issues. May be just try to see your console if you see any other error throwing.

Comment: @tutorialfeed, There is no any error. weird thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to solve your problem and getting no issue. This is just a very simplified example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r29kyu

As per my understanding you want to hide the div with class `alert alert-warning alert-dismissible` as well. If so than you have to put it inside `ng-container` as well.